# Check if string "is" javascript code with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For a very simple javascript template engine I need to check whether a given string *"is"* javascript code (like `if-else`,`for-loops` or `while-loops`). Therefore I'm using this very simple regex `/(:|=|{|})/g` (["tested" here](http://regexr.com/39l8q)). While this regex works almost anytime it somehow fails in some cases when I'm using it in a loop:

```
// Very simple regex to check if string "is" javascript code
var regFunc = /(:|=|{|})+/g;
// For testing: a simple javascript array
var testArray = [
  // expected: false, is: false
  'string',
  // expected: true, is: true
  'for(var i=0; i<total;i++) {',
  // expected: true, is: false (??)
  '}',
  // expected: true, is: true
  '}'
];

for( var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++ ) {
  console.log(
    testArray[ i ],
    regFunc.test( testArray[ i ] )
  );
}
```

You can check the console output on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/guwaleyipuyu/1/edit). So I'm wondering why the first "{" outputs `false` and the second one outputs `true` (which is what I expect for both)?

Comment: I don't get it. How is `/[:={}]+/` supposed to test if a string is javascript or not? For example it matches `::::` which is definitely not javascript. Care to tell us more about the actual problem?

Comment: @georg That's why I wrote "in" in brackets. I'm aware that this regex doesn't check for valid javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN - Regex - Test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

This mean you'll have to reinitialize your regexp object each time you're testing a string.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by "reinitialize". I tried removing the global flag and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Either removing the global flag or do `regFunc = /(:|=|{|})+/g;` before each test.

Comment: Using `reg.lastIndex = 0;` before each test probably works as well then.